# How to probe std::mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I have two threads. Both are talking to GPU. The first one is responsible for rendering the other one for loading stuff.  When the first one is actually rendering and not doing other things the second one has to stop. They can run in parallel but that will introduce framerate spikes. So it's ok to make one loop in loading thread but no more.  I implemented this behavior with std::mutex but i don't like it since the second thread is actually toggling mutex and could slow down rendering thread. How can it be implemented in cleaner way?

```
//Master thread
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(gpuMutex);
    // rendering
}

//Slave thread
while(!toLoadQueue.isEmpty()) {
    gpuMutex.lock();
    gpuMutex.unlock();
    // loading
}
```

**Edit:**
[image: Comparison] Comparison of mine(blue) and @barry's(red) code. (less spike is better)

[image: Visualization] Visualization of how threads should behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `condition_variable` and an `atomic<bool>`:

```
// in master
available = false;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(gpuMutex);
// [ do stuff ... ]
// ok ready to let go
available = true;
cv.notify_one();
```

The slave then just `wait`s on the `condition_variable` to be `notify`ed. We add in the `atomic<bool>` just to avoid spurious wakeup.

```
// in slave
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(gpuMutex);
cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return available.load(); });
```

Comment: Well, i am really confused. Do you know why your solution works so much better?

Comment: It is inefficient for `available` to be atomic.  It can be a plain `bool` as it is always read & written with `gpuMutex` locked.  Otherwise, I agree this is the way to go.

Comment: @Keo I can't articulate a reason well enough for me to have posted it as an answer if that was a question. I guess `condition_variable` is designed to solve this problem - so it does it well?

Comment: @Keo To me it looks like your original code is able to run multiple times while the gpu mutex is not locked. The solution in this answer ensures that it only runs once.

Comment: @typ1232 That would explain the difference. Because there would be less or no overlaps.